# Downgrading a WP3.3.1 Network Install

Tags: multisite, uninstallation

Good Morning--

Today I need to downgrade a site from a WP network install to a normal WP install.  I thought this would be simple -- just removing these lines from wp-config.php:
        define( 'MULTISITE', true );
        define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
        $base = '/xxx/blog/';
        define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'xxx.xxx.xxx' );
        define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/xxx/blog/' );
        define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
        define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
and changing
        define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
to
        define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false);

But I consistently am getting a: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. when I try to login as an administrator on the site.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance for all your insights!
Stephen

Comment: Could you not just have it as a multisite with a single site on the network? You're not supposed to go from multisite to single site, only single to multisite, it was never intended to go the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

- Create a new WordPress install in the place you want your install to be
- Put it in maintenance mode
- migrate the content
- Log in and adjust options accordingly

To migrate the content you have two choices:

**1**
 - Copy the data from the tables of the blog/site that you want to revert to a single site over the top of the data in the tables of the new WordPress install
 - Adjust the options accordingly
 - Copy over the themes plugins and uploads

**2**

- Do a WordPress export on the multisite
- Import on the new Wordpress install

**But, my recommendation is:**

Don't bother. Remove all sites in the network except for the one you want, and then leave it. You've got a single site running and it works the same as a single site, its administered the same way, looks the same way, has the same codebase, its just got a network admin for if you change your mind in the future.

Moving back to a single site is just unnecessary hassle. If you've got a client who might get confused, just make them an admin on that site and make sure the network admin and related items are visible only to super admins like yourself, so that they are none the wiser.